# Visual Studio C++ Project Linker2019 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a simple project with the following files, but could not get it to run.

[image]

multiplication.h

```
class Multiplication{
public:
float multiply(float x, float y);
};
```

subtraction.h

```
class Subtraction{
public:
float subtract(float x, float y);
};
```

multiplication.cpp

```
#include "multiplication.h"

float Multiplication::multiply(float x, float y){
float prod;
prod = x*y;
return prod;
};
```

subtraction.cpp

```
#include "subtraction.h"

float Subtraction::subtract(float x, float y){
float diff;
diff = x-y;
return diff;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "subtraction.h"
#include "multiplication.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
//lets calculate 4*5-20
Multiplication* m = new Multiplication();
Subtraction* s = new Subtraction();
std::cout<<s->subtract(m->multiply(4,5),20);
}
```

However, I get the following errors when I try to build the project and could not figure out why, would love to get some help:)

[image]

Comment: You selected the wrong type of project in Visual Studio project wizard. Instead of a Console application you selected some type of GUI application.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks! I changed to console application and it worked.